# Asymptotic for degree

Tags: asymptotics

How can I find asymptotic for $\chi(n)$, if $\chi^{\chi^\chi} = n$. Is here self-qualification estimation? I tried to take the logarithm of both sides, but to nothing has come.

Comment: You took the logarithm only once? Try doing it twice.

Comment: I have got $xln(x) + ln(ln(x)) = ln(ln(n))$, and what should i do next? $xln(x) = O(ln(ln(n))) ? $

Comment: So if I have $xln(x) = O(ln(ln(n)))$, can I say that $lnx + ln(ln(x)) = O(ln(ln(ln(n))))$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Only yesterday, eh? Duplicates tend to flock together, it seems.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen,, when this happens I always wonder if the askers are taking the same class.